# Find option on SQL Server for execute process in Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server

I am a new developer in a system, I will comment a little of the problem clarifying that there is no documentation of this process where I work and that's why I ask around here.

We have 2 services and 2 databases, these databases are synchronized with a program developed by the company, the program is very old in fact no one touch this in many years and is made in visual basic 6.0. I will call this program "synchronizer".

I have a table where I add a record, by adding this record runs the "synchronizer", this "synchronizer" runs several sp, also for what I understand the code of the "synchronizer" prints in console everything that runs.

Question:

This "synchronizer" is in the SQL Server, my question is: where is configured the execution of this type of programs in the SQL Server? Is there an option to see the console in SQL Server of this program? Where can I find some option that links this program with the SQL Server?

Comment: Something like this: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/execute-vbscript-commands-or-vbs-files-via-t-sql?

Comment: @PM77-1 I just looked for something similar to the link, I didn't find anything, where I work

Comment: I doubt that adding the record *runs the "synchronizer"*. It's more likely that the "synchronizer* runs all the time, and monitors the database for changes and then does something when that change happens. The only way it could happen the way you describe is in a trigger on the table, and (AFAIK) you can't launch an external application from within a trigger, and if you could and you inserted 100 rows you'd end up with 100 copies of the "synchronizer8 running at the same time.

Comment: You might have an SQL Server Agent job running which monitors that table for unprocessed records.

Comment: @KenWhite the sinchronizer run almost 40 store procedures and execute these store procedures when add a record on a Table. I review this process.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said. It's still more likely the synchronizer monitors the table, rather than that changes to the table run the synchronizer.

Comment: @KenWhite I just checked now,  there is no trigger programmed to execute anything

Comment: Yes, I know. Read what I wrote again. I said I did NOT think it was a trigger. Again, I think the synchronizer runs all the time and monitors the database, NOT that the database launches the synchronizer.

Comment: One option is a **trigger** on each of the tables. It could also be a **scheduled task** or **windows service** on the host machine, that merely polls the database on a schedule, especially if you have **change data capture**.

Comment: if I thought of some of those options I just want to emphasize that there is a program in visual basic 6.0 where it has a connection to the database and runs the stored procedures is called cls_SYNCDownload.cls and run from a progra.bar